# Azure Active Directory authentication from AspNet Identity error 400 bad request after submit login form

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have tried to implement the following sample program from github to check with my Azure Active directory user's login

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect

When I try to run the application,  it leads to azure portal login, when submit with credentials the browser keep on refresh the loop continuously (400  bad request).

any help would be appriciated

Comment: Are you running http or https?  Does the reply url defined in the azure ad application match the local url exactly?

Comment: Which one gives the 400? AAD or your app? Could you check with F12 tools and maybe show the network trace? You also need to show how OpenIDConnect is setup, as well as your AAD app settings from the portal.

Comment: Even a small spelling mistake will get a 400 bad request, double check your code include url, tenantid,clientid...

Comment: Sorry for the delayed Response, Thanks for your response and this is helped me to sort out the issue following is the reason causing issue 1. I have created too many apps in the Azure AD so that it has larger header cookies and 2. It has the problem on from azure https to our http URL and we have override the secure . these solved the issue